# How can i change gradient Color of polygon using google-maps-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using **google-maps-react** in my current application to show the map, here I have a requirement to display gradient Polygon, but i am unable to do so.
Currently these below attributes i can see from documentation.

- fillColor
- fillOpacity
- strokeColor
- strokeOpacity
- strokePosition
- strokeWeight

I have also tried to add an an image url using below code but unable to do so, Can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Polygon } from 'google-maps-react';

class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const triangleCoords = [
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
      { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
      { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 }
    ];

    const polygonOptions = {
      paths: triangleCoords,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      // Use the gradient image as the fillPattern
      fillPattern: 'URL_TO_YOUR_GRADIENT_IMAGE',
    };

    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={10}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 }}
      >
        <Polygon
          paths={triangleCoords}
          options={polygonOptions}
        />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
})(MapContainer);
```

Comment: There's no gradient option as of now, but you can file a feature request for it. Just make sure to put your use case. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Comment: I have raised a feature request they may provide some solution. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/300128121